# Filter high-order function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Using 'filter' I need to write a code to reate a procedure called (count-zeros lst) that counts how many 0s are in a number. Sample output: (count-zeros '(1 1 0 1 0 0)) should give 3

```
(define filter (lambda (pred a-list)
    (if (null? a-list)
        '()
        (if (pred (car a-list))
            (cons (car a-list) (filter pred (cdr a-list)))
            (filter pred (cdr a-list)))))) 

(define (count-zeros lst)
  (filter zero? (length lst)))
```

I know the logic is right but I have troubles with the implementation and making the code work. Please help me to improve the code.

Comment: Side note: In real Racket code, instead of what sounds like homework, you'd use [`count`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29): `(count (lambda (n) (= n 0)) a-list)`

Answer (score 1):

Read the problem statement *carefully*, and compare it against what you wrote: it says *count* the number of zeroes, but you're taking the length of the list (which returns a number!) and then trying to filter the zeroes out of that number, which doesn't make sense. It's the other way around:

```
(define (count-zeros lst)
  (length (filter zero? lst)))
```

First we filter just the zeroes, which returns a list, and then we get the length of that list.